# Let $R$ be a commutative ring with no zero divisors, then $R$ can be embedded in an integral domain $S$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with no zero divisors, then $R$ can be embedded in an integral domain $S$.

I am facing a problem to find the monomorphism $f: R \to S$.

Will the function $f(a) ={a \over 1}$ work here?

Comment: In these types of questions, usually the natural maps are the right ones.

Comment: what will be the map??

Comment: Does $R$ have identity?

Comment: it is not mentioned

Comment: So your problem is how to add an identity? Otherwise I think $R$ is itself an integral domain.

Comment: yes...i have to into a identity

Answer (score 1):

How do you even know $\frac{a}{1} \in S$, since you haven't even said what "$S$" is?

Hint #1: Prove $T = R -\{0\}$ is closed under multiplication.

Hint #2: Can we choose $S = T^{-1}R$? Is this an integral domain?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply take $S$ to be the fraction field, the construction of which is similar to the unital case: Let $T:=R\backslash\{0\}$, if $T=\emptyset$, $R$ is zero ring and cannot be embedding to integral domain; otherwise $T$ is a multiplicative set, define $S:=T^{-1}R$. Note that $S$ is a field (in particular, it has identity, namely $\frac tt$ for any $t\in T$). Furthermore, $R$ can be embedded to $S$ via $f:R\to S, r\mapsto \frac{rt}t\ (t\in T)$.